# Show headings and then graphs in order inside loop in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to print headings and then two plots side by side in rmarkdown using a loop.

```
{r try, echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,results='asis',fig.show='hold',out.width="50%"}
states <- c("CA","ID","NV","WA")
timeframes <- c("DD_Data1","DD_Data2","DD_Data3")
for (i in 1:length(states)){
  cat(paste0("## ",states[i],"\n"))
  for (j in 1:length(timeframes)){
    cat(paste0("### ",timeframes[j],"\n"))
    df <- get(timeframes[j])
    df <- df %>% filter(Loan_State2==states[i])
    lorenz.c(data=df,ind.var="NetCash180",pred="FinalScoreAdjr",title="Lorenz Curve", InverseRelation = T)  
    lorenz.c(data=df,ind.var="NetCash180",pred="pred_mLimit_6.1_stand",title="Lorenz Curve", InverseRelation = T)  
  }
  
}
```

I wrote this code but it first generates all the headings and then the graphs are shown, but I want heading then sub heading and then the two graphs side by side. e.g. CA would be heading and then sub heading would be DD_Data1 and then the two graphs.

Comment: It's hard to try and help without a reproducible example, or at least a sketch of what you are trying to achieve.